# Can't execute ignite chain serve in firmachain project

Tags: go, cosmos-blockchain

While I was trying to execute "ignite chain serve" in the firma project, I encountered the following bug.

```
> ·ignite chain serve
 Ignite CLI v0.27.1 is available!

 To upgrade your Ignite CLI version, see the upgrade doc: https://docs.ignite.com/guide/install.html#upgrading-your-ignite-cli-installation



Cosmos SDK's version is: stargate - v0.45.9

️  Building proto...
 Installing dependencies...
️  Building the blockchain...
cannot build app:

        error while running command go build -o /home/tinydever/go/bin/firmachaind -mod readonly -ldflags -X github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/version.Name=Firmachain -X github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/version.AppName=firmachaind -X github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/version.Version=0.3.5-patch -X github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/version.Commit=ac86456416cf590b081ddbe4ff8268e38c21adbd -X github.com/firmachain/firmachain/cmd/firmachaind/cmd.ChainID=imperium-4 .: # github.com/CosmWasm/wasmvm/internal/api

/home/tinydever/go/pkg/mod/github.com/!cosm!wasm/wasmvm@v1.1.1/internal/api/mocks.go:195:2: undefined: GasMeter
/home/tinydever/go/pkg/mod/github.com/!cosm!wasm/wasmvm@v1.1.1/internal/api/mocks.go:196:20: undefined: Gas
/home/tinydever/go/pkg/mod/github.com/!cosm!wasm/wasmvm@v1.1.1/internal/api/mocks.go:200:11: undefined: Gas
/home/tinydever/go/pkg/mod/github.com/!cosm!wasm/wasmvm@v1.1.1/internal/api/mocks.go:201:11: undefined: Gas
/home/tinydever/go/pkg/mod/github.com/!cosm!wasm/wasmvm@v1.1.1/internal/api/mocks.go:205:28: undefined: Gas
/home/tinydever/go/pkg/mod/github.com/!cosm!wasm/wasmvm@v1.1.1/internal/api/mocks.go:212:38: undefined: Gas
/home/tinydever/go/pkg/mod/github.com/!cosm!wasm/wasmvm@v1.1.1/internal/api/mocks.go:216:32: undefined: Gas
/home/tinydever/go/pkg/mod/github.com/!cosm!wasm/wasmvm@v1.1.1/internal/api/mocks.go:230:42: undefined: Gas
/home/tinydever/go/pkg/mod/github.com/!cosm!wasm/wasmvm@v1.1.1/internal/api/mocks.go:329:7: undefined: KVStore
/home/tinydever/go/pkg/mod/github.com/!cosm!wasm/wasmvm@v1.1.1/internal/api/mock_failure.go:15:27: undefined: GoAPI
/home/tinydever/go/pkg/mod/github.com/!cosm!wasm/wasmvm@v1.1.1/internal/api/mocks.go:329:7: too many errors
: exit status 1
Waiting for a fix before retrying...
```

Is this because of the incompatible version?

The ignite version required for the project is 0.23.0 so I installed it but genie says this is becaused of the versioning.

Comment: cgo is required to build [github.com/CosmWasm/wasmvm](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/CosmWasm/wasmvm#section-readme). Run `go env -w CGO_ENABLED=1` to enable cgo and try again.